# Display the array content in a way the user will be able to select option and navigate the content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a Computer Base Test project where user will be tested and graded on selected subject. I have a set of questions with options in the database. I want to be able to display the question in a way the user will be able to select option and navigate the questions. I am using php/mysql.

Here is my question table structure:

```
question(id,subject,question,optA,optB,optC,optD,answer).
```

My php code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * from {$table} WHERE subject={$subj}";
$question_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);.
```

I know I will need javascript to do this, Pls help me out.

Comment: First of all, you need to decide, how to do it in HTML. Do you plan to use drop down lists or radio buttons? Only after it you have to start php implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a ajax request to the server to get these data. You can use jquery AJAX for that.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "question.php",
   context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#question').html(data);
});
```

After getting the questions from the server through AJAX request. You can display the question below the option.

For more info about Jquery Ajax, Refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thanks, I have been able to get all the questions to the page, where i am stuck is how to display a question @ a time to the user and navigate the questions with back and forward button. @llya i am using radiobutton control for the options.